# How can I (efficiently) chain my promise that returns an array with value rather than promiess?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise chain that finds an array. I want the array to return some results (where in the future I can set it to a state variable). However, I am only getting promises. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

For now, I am console logging the items in my array to see if it returns the value, rather than the Promise.

```
addIPFSItem = () => {

    var finalItems = []
    var searchAddress = "0x9Cf0dc46F259542A966032c01DD30B8D1c310e05";

    const contract = require('truffle-contract')
    const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract)
    simpleStorage.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)

this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
  simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
    this.simpleStorageInstance = instance

    return this.simpleStorageInstance.getLength(searchAddress);
  }).then((accountLength) => {

    var movieItems = []
    var i;
    var indexCounter = 0;
    //WITHIN THIS LOOP extend the chain to add to movies
    for (i = 0; i < accountLength; i++) {

      var p = this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }).then((hashVal) => {
        return hashVal;
      }).then((hashVal)=>{
          var ipfsPrefix = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/";
          var ipfsURL = ipfsPrefix + hashVal;
          return ipfsURL
      })

      var k = this.simpleStorageInstance.getTitle(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }).then((title) => {
        return title;
      })

      var l = this.simpleStorageInstance.getContents(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }).then((contents) => {
        return contents;
      })

      movieItems.push({id: i, poster_src: p, title: k, overview: l})
      indexCounter++
      console.log('counter: ', i, p, k, l)
    }

    //return items
    return movieItems
  }).then((array) =>{

    var i
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      console.log('Array item: ', array[i])
    }

    return finalItems
  })
})
}
```

I don't know if I need to chain the `var p`, `var k`, `var l` when adding it to `movieItems` array. Supposedly, after I push to `movieItems`, I can then try and get each value within the array as I have already retrieved the values right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cheat the promises here!

When you run

```
var l = this.simpleStorageInstance.getContents(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }).then((contents) => {
  console.log('Retrieved contents');
  return contents;
});
movieItems.push({id: i, poster_src: p, title: k, overview: l});
console.log('Pushed!')
```

the javascript engine is going say "I'll put this Promise into `l` directly and continue to `movieItems.push`". If you run this, you'll see the logs appear as

- Pushed!
- Retrieved contents

There is a lot to learn about promises, so I can't explain everything in this one post. A quick fix for now, assuming you have an environment or build tool that supports it, is using `async/await`. That way you can make javascript "just wait" until your promises are resolved.

first you change
`}).then((accountLength) => {` to `}).then(async (accountLength) => {`
which tells javascript you are going to use `await` and work with Promises inside the function. Then you can, instead of using `.then`, use `await` like this:

```
// Here I use `await` instead of `.then` to make the promise return "normally"
var hashVal = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress });
// I do the transformations you did inside `.then(() => { ... })` "just" after the function call
var ipfsPrefix = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/";
var ipfsURL = ipfsPrefix + hashVal;
var p = ipfsURL;

// Again, using `await` instead of `.then`
var k = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getTitle(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress })

var l = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getContents(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress });
```

This would make your function actually return an array of values instead of an array with promises inside.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Absolutely correct. I never used Async/Await much and didn't realize how much simpler it could be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value of variables `p`, `k`, and `l` *are* Promises. And they will always be promises, because that's what `this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook()` et al return. Adding a `.then()` to them doesn't make them synchronously represent their values, they are still Promises. You need to compose Promises cleverly in order to ensure the values you want are available at the time and place you want them - I suggest you do more reading on how they work.

A straightforward fix might be to simply use `await`. It basically pauses execution until the asynchronous Promise finishes, and will ensure that `p`, `k`, and `l` represent the values that you expect of them. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
addIPFSItem = () => {
  var finalItems = []
  var searchAddress = "0x9Cf0dc46F259542A966032c01DD30B8D1c310e05";
  const contract = require('truffle-contract')
  const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract)
  simpleStorage.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)

  this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
    simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
      this.simpleStorageInstance = instance

      return this.simpleStorageInstance.getLength(searchAddress);
    }).then((accountLength) => {

      var movieItems = []
      var i;
      var indexCounter = 0;
      //WITHIN THIS LOOP extend the chain to add to movies
      for (i = 0; i < accountLength; i++) {

        let p = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getBook(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress }).then((hashVal) => {
          return hashVal;
        }).then((hashVal) => {
          var ipfsPrefix = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/";
          var ipfsURL = ipfsPrefix + hashVal;
          return ipfsURL
        });

        let k = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getTitle(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress });

        let l = await this.simpleStorageInstance.getContents(searchAddress, i, { from: searchAddress });

        movieItems.push({ id: i, poster_src: p, title: k, overview: l })
        indexCounter++
        console.log('counter: ', i, p, k, l)
      }

      //return items
      return movieItems
    }).then((array) => {

      var i
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log('Array item: ', array[i])
      }

      return finalItems
    })
  })
}
```

P.S. If you're using `const` you should be using `let` instead of `var`. There is basically no reason whatsoever to use `var` in ES6.